# How to display the non-sparse parts of a sparse file?

Tags: text-processing, sparse-files

Imagine a file created with:

```
truncate -s1T file
echo test >> file
truncate -s2T file
```

I now have a 2 tebibyte file (that occupies 4kiB on disk), with `"test\n"` written in the middle.

How would I recover that `"test"` efficiently, that is without having to read the whole file.

```
tr -d '\0' < file
```

Would give me the result but that would take hours.

What I'd like is something that outputs only the non-sparse parts of the file (so above only `"test\n"` or more likely, the 4kiB block allocated on disk that stores that data).

There are APIs to find out which part of the file are *allocated* (FIBMAP, FIEMAP, SEEK_HOLE, SEEK_DATA...), but what tools expose those?

A portable solution (at least to the OSes that support those APIs) would be appreciated.

Comment: How efficient is `strings`?

Comment: @glennjackman, less than `tr` since it still reads the whole file and does more than just removing the NUL bytes.

Answer (score 6):

The best I could come up with so far is (ksh93, using `filefrag` from `e2fsprogs` 1.42.9 (some older versions have a different API), on extent based file systems on Linux):

```
#! /bin/ksh93 -
export LC_ALL=C
for file do
filefrag -vb1 -- "$file" |
  while IFS=": ." read -A a; do
    [[ $a = +([0-9]) ]] && [[ ${a[@]} != *unwritten* ]] &&
      command /opt/ast/bin/head -s "${a[1]}" -c "${a[7]}" -- "$file"
  done
done
```

`filefrag` reports the extents of the file using the FIEMAP ioctl for the filesystems that support it.

The `*unwritten*` part covers for the (non-sparse, but still full of zeros I'm not interested in) files that have been `fallocated` but not written to.

Recent versions of `bsdtar` or `star` can use some of those APIs to generate a `tar` file that identifies the sparse sections as such. That would make for a more *portable* solution, but then one would have to parse the generated tar file to get the non-sparse sections.